# Do I have a GTX 1050 or a GTX 1050 Ti

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cryptomining

When I bought my laptop, they (the store) said that it has a GTX 1050 with 4 gigs of memory. My friend pointed out that only a GTX 1050 Ti has 4 gigs of memory. Furthermore, when I mine Ethereum in Nicehash, I can use the Daggerhashimoto algorithm which isn't supported in the GTX 1050.

Device Manager says I have a GTX 1050, but then how am I having a 4 GB memory one, and how am I mining with Daggerhashimoto?

[image: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050]

Device instance path: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8D&SUBSYS_07E11028&REV_A1\4&24CB4060&0&0008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/laptops/) says that both the 1050 and the 1050 *mobile versions* have up to 4 GB frame buffers.

But you're correct - per the [PCI ID repository](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10de) you don't have a 1050 Ti.  The Ti and non-Ti have different device IDs, and the mobile and non-mobile versions do also - four different device IDs. If it was really a 1050 Ti mobile it would be device 1c8c, not 1c8d.

(Thank you for posting the PnP ID, by the way. That helped a lot!)